# hibernate create AuxiliaryDatabaseObject with annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I've read this in the latest hibernate document https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-database-objects

However, the document only shows how to create the database object in XML mapping. I think XML is more or less old-style, and currently, I created all entity mapping with annotations, don't want to create an XML just for that. Is it possible to do it with annotation?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate Annotations does not need mapping *.hbm.xml file. Hence, you need to add the auxiliary objects programmatically.

The database object in the given link has 3 things:

1. Create
2. Drop
3. Dialect

[image]

- As per your needs you can add auxiliary objects like in examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.AuxiliaryDatabaseObject).
- Here, is another [example](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration/addAuxiliaryDatabaseObject) of *addAuxiliaryDatabaseObject* to Configuration.
- You can use [AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/relational/AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject.html) class which implements AuxiliaryDatabaseObject interface. [Example](https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject) of *appliesToDialect* using AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject .
- The [AuxiliaryDatabaseObject](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/relational/AuxiliaryDatabaseObject.html) interface has methods like *sqlCreateStrings*, *sqlDropStrings* etc. Here, is [example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=lamsfoundation%2Flams%2Flams-master%2F3rdParty_sources%2Fhibernate-core%2Forg%2Fhibernate%2Ftool%2Fschema%2Finternal%2FStandardAuxiliaryDatabaseObjectExporter.java) usage of these methods.
- In the end, these objects needs to be added to the [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) & can be done using [addAuxiliaryDatabaseObject](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addAuxiliaryDatabaseObject-org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.AuxiliaryDatabaseObject-) API.